# How to wrap a Mono in an outer Mono with timeout?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive, reactor

I have a method that returns an async `Mono`. It could be a long running webservice call, database lookup, or whatever.

Now I want to set a maximum timeout of that long running method of 60s. After that timeout, the result can be neglected.

Further, if the result was not received within 15s, I already want to return with a fallback value. **Anyways** the long running call should continue up to 60s and being process async if result was recevied within this 60s (even though the main thread then already answered with the fallback value).

Question: is it correct to wrap the `Mono` inside another `Mono` for this?

Example:

```
public class Service {
    public Mono longRunningProcess() {
        //...
    }
}

Mono.just(
    service.longRunningProcess()
        .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
        .doOnSuccess(rsp -> {
            //process result up to 1 minute
        }
        .block()
    )
    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15)
    .onErrorResume(ex -> {
        //provide fallback after 15s already
        return Mono.just(Mono.just(getFallbackResult()));
    }
    .block();
```

Comment: Do I get it right that you want the 60 seconds timeout process to update your fallback value, and after 15 seconds you return the fallback value no matter if the first async call is done or not?

Comment: I believe the major problem with your design is that timeout implies cancellation as well. So, when your 15-secs mono times out and falls back to your default behavior, this automatically cancelled your 60-secs mono. That being said, the pattern of returning something to the client while you wait for some pending processing sounds smelly to me.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking is against reactive concept, I'd recommend to look at

```
public static <T> Mono<T> create(Consumer<MonoSink<T>> callback)
```

So transformed example from your question:

```
Mono.create(sink -> {
                    service.longRunningProcess()
                            .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                            .subscribe(
                                    res -> {
                                        //process the result
                                        //this code would be reached anyway if not error
                                        sink.success(res);
                                    },
                                    e -> {
                                        //process error
                                        //this code would be reached anyway error
                                        sink.error(e);
                                    });
                })
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    return Mono.just(getFallbackResult());
                })
                .subscribe(result -> {/* process the result */});
```

so even after 15 seconds and getting the fallback result, longRunningProcess still will be processed

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should be enough for you without that wrapping:

```
/**
 * Switch to a fallback {@link Mono} in case no item arrives within the given {@link Duration}.
 *
 * <p>
 * If the fallback {@link Mono} is null, signal a {@link TimeoutException} instead.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/timeoutFallbackForMono.svg" alt="">
 *
 * @param timeout the timeout before the onNext signal from this {@link Mono}
 * @param fallback the fallback {@link Mono} to subscribe to when a timeout occurs
 *
 * @return a {@link Mono} that will fallback to a different {@link Mono} in case of timeout
 */
public final Mono<T> timeout(Duration timeout, Mono<? extends T> fallback) {
```

So, if your main `Mono` does not return in time, your go to desired fallback. That's it: I don't anything else to overcomplicate the logic.

Comment: I think you got me wrong: I want a "main" flow that executes `doOnSuccess()` if the process returned within 60s. Then I want another outer flow that stops waiting for the result, and serves a fallback instead after 15s. **Anyways** the main flow of 60s should continue meanwhile and still execute `doOnSuccess()`, even if the 15s flow already returned the fallback.

Comment: I still think that API I suggest in the answer is correct. Of course the `Mono fallback`  may have its own `timeout()` with its own fallback and so on. The `.block()` in your code is fully wrong: I don't recommend to use it in production at all - maximum for testing, but no blocking should appear in your real code.

Comment: For the fact to "provide a fallback for a mono timeout", yes your api is probably the correct method call. **But**: I'm more looking for a way to set **two** timeouts: one that short cirtuit the call and returns the fallback, **meanwhile** the inner/second timer should still continue to run (in my example for max 60s), and **also** process the response!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way with pure `Mono`s, but one with `Future` as follows:

```
List<String> results = Flux.fromIterable(reqs)
    .flatMap(req -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            try {
                return longRunningProcess(req)
                         //inner timeout continues even if outer future is timed out
                        .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
                        .doOnSuccess(rsp -> {
                            //process result up to 1 minute
                        }
                        .toFuture()
                        .get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //outer short cirtuit timeout
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //on future timeout (15s)
                return getFallbackResult();
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))
    .collectList()
    .block();
```

Though it works, I'm still open for improvements on how to achieve the same with reactive monos only.